# How can I display these array of items in one column?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mui-datatable

This is my code to get the data from the firestore.

```
class PendingOrdersTable extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { orders: [] };
  }

  columns = [
    "Order ID",
    "Items",
  ];
  options = {
    filter: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    try {
      firestore
        .collection("orders")
        .where("orderStatus", "==", "Pending")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          const orders = [];
          snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            const orderID = doc.id;
            const data = doc.data();
            data.items.forEach((item) => {
              orders.push({
                "Order ID": doc.id,
                Items: [item.productName, "(", item.qty, ")"],
              });
            });

          });
          this.setState({ orders: orders });
          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.orders));
        });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MUIDataTable
          title={"Orders"}
          columns={this.columns}
          data={this.state.orders}
          options={this.options}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

]

The problem with this is that it renders separate rows for the same document ID. It's supposed to display the [q2P7DafXDvma6eMztEir],Tuna Pizza(1) and Vegetable Pizza(2) in one column.

[image]

this is the JSON object:

```
    [
      {
        "Order ID": "q2P7DafXDvma6eMztEir",
        Name: "Ruhn",
        "Total Amount": 390,
        Items: ["Tuna Pizza", "(", 1, ")"],
      },
      {
        "Order ID": "q2P7DafXDvma6eMztEir",
        Name: "Ruhn",
        "Total Amount": 390,
        Items: ["Vegetable Pizza", "(", 2, ")"],
      },

];
```

This is the data in firestore and the "Items" here is in array:
[image]

Comment: console.log() your orders, it seems like your orders array has 2 rows.

Comment: If you don't want the "items" to be in different "order" rows, why are you adding each "item" individually as an order? Just.... don't do that?

Comment: @Chase My Items in the firestore is in array, is it possible to fetch the items without mapping it?

Comment: My point is, you are getting the data as "orders" with the consolidation of items you want in the end in the first place. You're explicitly going out of your way to change it to be a list of "items" instead, not orders. Just leave it in the shape it came from the DB in which each order already contains it's respective items.

Comment: @Chase so then I'll remove the  data.items.forEach((item)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `snapshot.docs.map` method with the below code snippet, it will append the items for same `doc.id` and will provide the desired output.

```
const orders = [];
snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    const items = []
    doc.data().items.forEach((item) => {
        items.push(`${item.productName}(${item.qty})`);
    });
    orders.push({
        "Order ID": doc.id,
        Items: items
    })
});
```